# adding additional layers to existing toggle visibility buttons

Tags: mapbox, toggle, raster, visibility, layer

I have pieced together the following code using examples on Mapbox... https://codepen.io/charlie-enright/pen/ZExKOGB?editors=0010

What I want to do now is add another raster layer but have its visibility controlled by one of the existing buttons (the "geophys")button rather than to have to add an extra button.
Is it possible to have two separate raster layers controlled by the same toggle button with the script I have used? If so how will I go about doing this?

The code for the additional raster layer I want to add to be controlled by the geophys button is:

```
map.addSource('rudbaxton', {
            'type': 'raster',
            'url': 'mapbox://charlie-enright.chlrzasw'
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'geophys1',
            'source': 'rudbaxton',
            'type': 'raster'
        });
```

On top of this I would like the opacity control to adjust the opacity for the two raster layers controlled by the "geophys" button. is this possible to do as well?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The way the example you used is set up, the text in the button must exactly match the name of the layer you want to toggle.

This line gets the text from the button that was clicked:
`const clickedLayer = this.textContent;`

This line gets the current visibility of the layer with the same name const visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, "visibility");`

To control two layers with one button click, you just need to add some logic to check for which button was clicked, and respond accordingly:

```
link.onclick = function (e) {
  const clickedButtonText = this.textContent;
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  if (clickedButtonText === "geophys") {
    // assuming your two layers should always be on or off together, only check the current visibility of one of them
    const visibility = map.getLayoutProperty("some-first-layer", "visibility");

    // Toggle layer visibility by changing the layout object's visibility property.
    if (visibility === "visible") {
      map.setLayoutProperty("some-first-layer", "visibility", "none");
      map.setLayoutProperty("some-second-layer", "visibility", "none");

      this.className = "";
    } else {
      this.className = "active";
      map.setLayoutProperty("some-first-layer", "visibility", "visible");
      map.setLayoutProperty("some-second-layer", "visibility", "visible");

    }
  }

  // repeat the above if statement for the other button(s)
};
```

As a bonus, this means you can use any text you want in the buttons, which might be a little more human-friendly than using the layer names!

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me again Chris. I tried putting your code into mine but I get an error message saying "can't find the variable ClickedButtonText"